# Locating and Installing a program (Heroku Toolbelt)

Tags: centos, windows, virtualbox

I'm new to Linux and Heroku. I downloaded the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/standalone) into my CentOS/VirtualBox setup using the following command:

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
```

However, according to the man pages, wget just downloads files, it does not install (is this correct?). I double checked to see if Heroku Toolbelt was installed with this command:

```
heroku login
```

but I got a `command not found` error.

I also do not know the name of the Heroku Toolbelt file that I downloaded, but I assumed it was `install.sh` but all I see in my current directory is: `install.log` and `install.log.syslog`

I also did this command

```
which heroku
```

but I got `no Heroku in ...` message

My question is: how do I install the Heroku Toolbelt? What commands do I use? How do I identify the file that was downloaded in the first place? Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: What the the install log file say? (And no, you didn't just download it, you ran it "on the fly" - pay attention to what commands you run, that's pretty much as dangerous as clicking on random .exe files you receive by email if you don't trust the source.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you installed as root/sudo, after installing you get prompted to:

```
Add the Heroku CLI to your PATH using:
$ echo 'PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
Installation complete
```

So, if you add it to your `PATH` in `~/.profile`, e.g.:

```
PATH=/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH
```

and restart your session, it should work:

```
whereis heroku
heroku: /usr/local/heroku /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku
which heroku
/usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku
```

and:

```
heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email:
```

Comment: when I do `whereis heroku` I get this result: `heroku: /usr/local/heroku`. But when I do `which heroku` I get this: `/usr/bin/which: no heroku in (/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/me/bin)`. When I do `heroku login` I get this message: `-bash: heroku: command not found`.

Answer (score 0):

On Centos 6 the profile-file is called `.bash_profile` (not `.profile`)
Edit your `.bash_profile` and add the path to heroku to the existing PATH specifier

```
# User specific environment and startup programs
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin
export PATH
```

Worked for me!